# Gender method not accessible in rails, even though it's in the table

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

So I'm trying to set a conditional statement for what images should be displayed

This is the section in my home/index view file

```
<% if @cloth.gender == "Female" && @cloth.size == "2T-3T" || "4T-5T" %>
```

This returns an error in the browser:

```
undefined method `gender' for #<Array:0x4d2c578>
```

I set the home controller to:

```
def index
  @cloth = Cloth.all
end
```

So it should be able to access all of "cloth", but it isn't.  When I go into the rails console I can access cloth.gender.  Not sure what to do here...

Entire code available at https://github.com/yahtaa/oslr

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A better way to do this would be to use the `each` method on @cloths:

```
<% @cloths.each do |cloth| %<
  <% if cloth.gender == "Female" && cloth.size == "2T-3T" || "4T-5T" %>
....
```

Notice I said @cloths...you should probably change your index def to `@cloths = Cloth.all` (just so your code is a bit more clear).

EDIT

As indicated in comments and in codeit's answer, there is a problem with the conditional as you initially wrote it. Another way of writing it would be

```
<% if cloth.gender == "Female" && (cloth.size == "2T-3T" || cloth.size == "4T-5T") %>
```

Thanks to codeit for identifying this problem.

Comment: updated the home controller and conditional, page display again, but it is listing images that don't fall within the conditional.

Comment: What is being displayed? Try putting parentheses around the disjunct (i.e. right before 'cloth.size') and see if that helps at all.

Comment: '<% @cloths.each do |cloth| %>'
'<% if cloth.gender == "Female" && (cloth.size == "2T-3T" || "4T-5T") %>'

But it is displaying a record that is "Female" but size == "Small"

Comment: There it goes, parenthesis in the wrong place.  oops.  Thanks.

Comment: `(cloth.size == "2T-3T" || "4T-5T")` will return false when `cloth.size` value is `4T-5T`

Comment: No problem. Zajn's answer explains why you had the problem you did, and demonstrates that error messages should steer you in the right direction.

Answer (score 3):

`Cloth.all` will return an instance of an `Array`. You'll need to either use `each` to iterate over all the instances that `Cloth.all` returns, or grab an instance with `@cloth[0]`, for example.

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
 @cloths.each do |cloth|
   if cloth.gender == "Female" && ["2T-3T", "4T-5T"].include?(cloth.size)
      #Or use  `if cloth.gender == "Female" && (cloth.size == "2T-3T" || cloth.szie == "4T-5T")`
   ..
 end
```

`(cloth.size == "2T-3T" || "4T-5T")` will return false when `cloth.size` value is `4T-5T`. Because `"2T-3T" || "4T-5T"` is always `2T-3T`

Comment: Good point. In my initial comment I was suggesting what you had commented out, but did so in a poor way.